# Sorting a dataset with a dataview

Tags: .net, sorting, dataset, dataview

This code correctly fetches data, and displays it; however, the sort is completely ignroed.

```
DataTable dt = f.Execute().Tables[0]; 
dt.DefaultView.Sort = summaryColumn;
rptInner.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
rptInner.DataBind();
```

Is there something I can do to force the view to sort itself?

(f.Execute() returns a dataset with at table at position 0, summaryColumn is the name of a column in the table, rptInner is a repeater control)

**edit**

summaryColumn is a string variable that has the exact name of the column I want to sort on. I am not using sproc or anything, the DataSet is given to me and I'm responsible for sorting it.

Comment: Has to be specific to your scenario (Repeater/ASP.NET?)... just mocked up a a simple DataTable with DefaultView.Sort assigned just like yours, then set dt.DefaultView as DataSource for a DataGridView and it sorts flawlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if summaryColumn is the name of the coulmn in the dataview that you want to sort on, put it into double quotes:

```
DataTable dt = f.Execute().Tables[0]; 
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "summaryColumn";
rptInner.DataSource = dv;
rptInner.DataBind();
```

If it's a string variable holding the name of the column, make sure it's value is the exact string name of the column you want to sort on...

Comment: I should've been more clear, summaryColumn is the name of a String object that contains the name of the column I'd like to sort on. I verified that the name of the column I am using is the same as what is in the Columns collection. Even the case is the same. Any thoughts?

Comment: @CharlesBretana: what if you wanted to sort with a second column (equivalent to ORDER BY A, B)

Comment: You Sir are a Legend! I've been looking for method, function, system or user made, something anything to sort my data. Up until this point, I've been doing it trough SQL, sending row name and asc or desc on call to perform a decent sorting, not anymore ! Nice one...

Comment: @Skippy, then ad the second column name to the string, separated from thje frist with a comma, as in `dv.Sort = "summaryColumnA,  otherColumnB";`  columns sort ascending by default. to make one descending add the string `desc`.  `dv.Sort = "summaryColumnA desc,  otherColumnB";`

Answer (score 0):

I sort on the server side, if you are using a stored proc from the execute call put an Order By statement on the result set (if it is SQL).

Comment: Sadly its not SQL, I get the dataset from a class library, I have no abbility to change it.